# How to create graphic instances in a java applet

Tags: java, testing, graphics, applet

We've just learned how to create our own class, and this particular assignment we had to work with graphics. We had to draw a crayon, and then create a test program where there are 5 crayons lined up next to one another (so we just change the color and x,y of each one). I know how to change the color and x,y coords, but my question is...

how do I 'print' each crayon? Yes, it's an applet and yes I know I need a .html file. But what exactly goes in the test program in order for the crayon to show up when I run the .html file? I've run non-applets before in test  programs using `System.out.println`, but never any graphics. Would it just be `System.out.println(Crayon);` ?

Also, how do I get multiple crayons? I'm assuming it's `Crayon crayons = new Crayon`;, and then the next one might be 'Crayon crayons2 = new Crayons;`? I'm not sure.

The x,y coordinates need to be modified w/each crayon, but the UML for the assignment told me not to make them instance variables but instead to put it in 'public void paint (Graphics g, int x, int y)'. What I have so far for the test program (may or may not be correct):

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class BoxOfCrayons extends JApplet {
   Crayon first = new Crayon (Color.red, 50, 250)
```

Comment: It really depends on how you've built your class. Most java graphics objects I have written, have a draw event in their class, which is called in the constructor. So calling `Crayon first = new Crayon(20, 40, 'red')` makes a red crayon at (20,40). If it is not in your constructor, you will have to run the draw function somehow. You will however have to edit your post and provide some code before we can give an more precise answer.

Comment: Do you want to draw text to the screen or the output text to the console?

Comment: *"Would it just be `System.out.println(Crayon);`?"*  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It would be best to become familiar with GUIs and custom painting using a desktop app. based on a `JFrame`.  Applets add complications of their own and are an 'advanced topic'.  Are you using Swing or AWT components?  Best to use Swing.

Comment: @Neograph734, thanks for the input. This is definitely helpful for changing color, but I don't need to change width or height. I need to change x,y, which isn't an instance variable but in 'public void paint (Graphics g, int x, int y)'. My constructor has (Color, width, height).

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want to draw the crayon in an applet.

Answer (score 0):

Start by having a read through [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html).

Basically, you will need to create some kind of list of `Cryon`s.  This can either be a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) or array, depending on what you know.  I would personally use a `ArrayList` as it's flexible and easy to use, but doesn't suffer from the same constraints as an array.

Next, create you're self a custom component (ie `BoxOfCryons`) which extends from `JPanel`.  Override this classes `paintComponent` method.  Within this method, run through the list of `Cryon`s and paint each one, incrementing the `x` offset by the width of the last `Cryon`.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (Crayon crayon : cryons) {
        crayon.paint(g2d, x, y);
        x += crayon.getWidth();
    }
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Create yourself a new class that extends from `JApplet`.  In it's `init` method, set the applets layout manager to `BorderLayout` and add an instance of the `BoxOfCryons` class to it.